# JQGrid - Empty Grid Not displaying Data

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I've been trying to get up and running on JQGrid. It's proving difficult. I have burned so much time on this, so I'll be very grateful to anyone who can help.

The actual grid code is as follows:

```
$(function () {
    $("#list2").jqGrid({
        url: '/Home/GetData',
        datatype: "json",        
        colNames: ['Inv No', 'Date', 'Client', 'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total', 'Notes'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 55 },
            { name: 'date', index: 'date', width: 90 },
            { name: 'client', index: 'client asc, date', width: 100 },
            { name: 'amount', index: 'amount', width: 80, align: "right" },
            { name: 'tax', index: 'tax', width: 80, align: "right" },
            { name: 'total', index: 'total', width: 80, align: "right" },
            { name: 'notes', index: 'notes', width: 150, sortable: false }
        ],
        jsonReader: {
            root: function(obj) {
                return $.parseJSON(obj);
            },
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records",
            repeatitems: true,
            cell: "cell",
            id: "id",
            userdata: "userdata"
        },
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        pager: '#pager2',
        sortname: 'id',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        caption: "JSON Example"
    });
    $("#list2").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager2', { edit: false, add: false, del: false });

});
```

The json returned from the server looks like this:

```
{
    "Page": "1",
    "Records": "13",
    "Total": 2,
    "UserData": {
        "Amount": 3220,
        "Name": "Totals:",
        "Tax": 342,
        "Total": 3564
    },
    "Rows": [{
        "Cell": {
            "Id": 13,
            "Date": "2014-09-01",
            "Client": "Client 3",
            "Amount": 1000.0,
            "Tax": 0.00,
            "Total": 1000.0,
            "Notes": null
        },
        "Id": 13,
    },
    {
        "Cell": {
            "Id": 14,
            "Date": "2014-09-01",
            "Client": "Client 4",
            "Amount": 2000.0,
            "Tax": 10.00,
            "Total": 2010.0,
            "Notes": null
        },
        "Id": 14,
    },
    {
        "Cell": {
            "Id": 15,
            "Date": "2014-09-01",
            "Client": "Client 5",
            "Amount": 3000.0,
            "Tax": 100.00,
            "Total": 3100.0,
            "Notes": null
        },
        "Id": 15,
    }]
}
```

Can anyone see the problem? Happy to provide all code. Using ASP.NET MVC as the server technology.

**Edit/Update**

I changed the server stuff so that all the properties in the json object are lowercase.
I also added an id property to each item inn the **rows** array. Still not working :(

Also, I am getting back-slashes in my json object, which is different from the example at the jqGrid site:

```
"{\"page\":\"1\",\"records\":\"13\",\"total\":2,\"userData\":{\"amount\":6110,\"name\":\"Totals:\",\"tax\":110,\"total\":6220},\"rows\":[{\"cell\":{\"id\":13,\"date\":\"2014-09-01\",\"client\":\"Client 3\",\"amount\":1000.0,\"tax\":0.00,\"total\":1000.0,\"notes\":null},\"id\":13},{\"cell\":{\"id\":14,\"date\":\"2014-09-01\",\"client\":\"Client 4\",\"amount\":2000.0,\"tax\":10.00,\"total\":2010.0,\"notes\":null},\"id\":14},{\"cell\":{\"id\":15,\"date\":\"2014-09-01\",\"client\":\"Client 5\",\"amount\":3000.0,\"tax\":100.00,\"total\":3100.0,\"notes\":null},\"id\":15}]}"
```

**Edit/Update**

I did finally get rid of the slashes. The combination which worked was to use JSON.NET to serialize the data to JSON and then to wrap that in a ContentResult. The JsonResult was serializing an object which had already been serialized to JSON.

Here is the server side code (C#):

```
public ActionResult GetData([FromUri]GridViewModel gridViewModel)
{
    var mockData = new MockData();

    mockData.Page = "1";
    mockData.Records = "13";
    mockData.Total = 2;
    mockData.UserData = new UserData
    {
        Amount = 6110,
        Name = "Totals:",
        Tax = 110,
        Total = 6220
    };

    mockData.Rows = new List<Object>
    {
        new
        {
            Cell = new Cell
            {
                Id = 13,
                Amount = 1000,
                Client = "Client 3",
                Date = DateTime.Now,
                Notes = null,
                Tax = 0.00M,
                Total = 1000
            },
            id = 13
        },
        new
        {
            Cell = new Cell
            {
                Id = 14,
                Amount = 2000,
                Client = "Client 4",
                Date = DateTime.Now,
                Notes = null,
                Tax = 10.00M,
                Total = 2010
            },
            id = 14
        },
        new
        {
            Cell = new Cell
            {
                Id = 15,
                Amount = 3000,
                Client = "Client 5",
                Date = DateTime.Now,
                Notes = null,
                Tax = 100.00M,
                Total = 3100
            },
            id = 15
        },
    };

    var jsonObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
        mockData,
        Formatting.None,
        new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
            DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd",
            StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeNonAscii
        }
        );

    //return Json(mockData, "application/json", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    return new ContentResult
    {Content = jsonObject, ContentType = "application/json"};
}

public class MockData
{
    public string Page { get; set; }
    public string Records { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public UserData UserData { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Object> Rows { get; set; }

}

public class UserData
{
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Tax { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
}

public class Cell
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Client { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public decimal Tax { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: have u tried using local data.. what it shows???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it's difficult if you post one question with two *different* JSON data. Which one you generate from the server? I recommend you to use Fiddler or Developer Tools of Internet Explorer (press <kbd>F12</kbd> to start and then use Network tab to start capturing) to capture the HTTP traffic between the server and the client. If the server response really the quoted string like

```
"{\"page\":\"1\",\"records\":\"13\",\"total\":2,...}
```

then you probably did **unneeded** serialization of object to JSON. Typically ASP.NET makes JSON serialization to you. The problem is that one can make JSON serialization of an object only, but the string too. In the case the quotes (`"`) in the string will be escaped (see [here](http://www.json.org/)). In the case you really can still use

```
jsonReader: {
    root: function (obj) {
        return $.parseJSON(obj).rows;
    },
    page: function (obj) {
        return $.parseJSON(obj).page;
    },
    total: function (obj) {
        return $.parseJSON(obj).total;
    },
    records: function (obj) {
        return $.parseJSON(obj).records;
    },
    repeatitems: false,
    userdata: "userData"
}
```

to read your data, but I would recommend you better to adjust your server response and remove additional unneeded JSON serialization.

Nevertheless jqGrid allows you read even the data which you posted. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/onefootswill.htm) demonstrates this. The only problem which one still have to fix is adding of `jsonmap` property to every column.

Typically the items of data looks like

```
{"cell": ["13", "2014-09-01", "Client 3", "1000", "0", "1000", ""], "id": 13}
```

or like

```
{
    "id": 13,
    "date": "2014-09-01",
    "client": "Client 3",
    "amount": 1000,
    "tax": 0,
    "total": 1000,
    "notes": null
}
```

and not like your data:

```
{
    "cell": {
        "id": 13,
        "date": "2014-09-01",
        "client": "Client 3",
        "amount": 1000,
        "tax": 0,
        "total": 1000,
        "notes": null
    },
    "id": 13
}
```

So to be able to read your data one have to add `jsonmap` property in every column definition of `colModel`:

```
{ name: "id", jsonmap: "cell.id", width: 55 },
{ name: "date", jsonmap: "cell.date", width: 90 },
{ name: "client", jsonmap: "cell.client", width: 100 },
{ name: "amount", jsonmap: "cell.amount", width: 80, align: "right" },
{ name: "tax", jsonmap: "cell.tax", width: 80, align: "right" },
{ name: "total", jsonmap: "cell.total", width: 80, align: "right" },
{ name: "notes", jsonmap: "cell.notes", width: 150, sortable: false }
```

Additionally I would recommend you to add the options `height: "auto"`, `gridview: true` and `autoencode: true` to the grid definition. You don't posted your server code. The jqGrid and the format of JSON data which you use required **server side** sorting, paging and searching/filtering of the data. If you work with not large dataset (for example less then 1000 rows) you should consider to return **all** data at once from the server and use `loadonce: true` option. In the case the `datatype` will be changed to `"local"` after the first loading of the data and the data will be sorted, paged and filtered by jqGrid internally.

Comment: Thanks for all the really helpful information. Interesting your point about my data, as it is what the server returns in the Json data demo http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html in the loading data section. That's where I got my data. Using Fiddler. I figured if I copied the demo, it would be fine. Cheers.

Comment: @onefootswill: You are welcome! I'm glad that I could help you. The demos from [the official jqGrid demo site](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) contains some examples created for **very old versions** of jqGrid. For example, the example "Loading Data"\"Array Data" first contains `i<=mydata.length` instead of `i<mydata.length` and seconds the usage of `addRowData` is the worst way to fill the grid. Instead of that on should use **gridview: true, data: mydata**. You don't referenced the exact demo which you use, but I believe that you can find other bad example here.

Comment: Hi Oleg, I've been reading the doco and I just want to know if this is out of date - http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data . Specifically, the bit about the default definition for the json data - which aligns with mine. It's hard to learn this grid when demos and doco are out of date :(

Comment: continuing my quest to learn this grid, I found a [tutorial link](http://www.smarttutorials.net/pagination-previous-next-first-and-last-button-using-jqgrid-php-mysql-jquery-and-ajax/) in a forum post in 2013. The shape of the json data is the exact same as that of mine. So now I just don't know what the json is supposed to look like.

Comment: @onefootswill: [The documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data) is up to date. jqGrid allows to read almost any input JSON data, but the problem is which JSON would be better. You need first good understand that **every row of grid** will have **unique id** attribute (rowid). You should include id in JSON data. Second you should decide whether you need *show the id* to the user (have the column with the id value). Next problem: whether you need use `repeatitems: false` or the default `repeatitems: true` format of data. And `loadonce: true` should be used?